# Neovim - Search for Digraph

Tags: neovim, digraphs

Is there a way to search for `Digraphs` in *Neovim 0.9.1*?

My Ideas so far:

- For example somehow using the `:digraphs` command?
- In *Vim* there is for example the `:help digraph-table` and you can search there with <kbd>/</kbd> but *Neovim* does not have that.

Comment: It seems that `:help digraph-table` is available from Neovim 0.6.1 to Neovim 0.9.4. Don't you have it?

Comment: Do you have still something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept an answer. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: `digraph-table` is still part of the runtime files distributed with Neovim. Perhaps you should check your installation?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt ehh... tbh I have no Idea what my problem was... Everything seems to work perfectly... I think I was just tired when I wrote this question or something^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Unicode](https://github.com/chrisbra/unicode.vim) plugin let you search the Unicode table and propose the corresponding digraph if it exist.

After you have downloaded the last Unicode data `:UnicodeDownload`.

You can use the command `:UnicodeTable` to see the table and search within.

The `:UnicodeSearch` search the table:

```
:UnicodeSearch e with acute
```

returns

```
   É    U+00C9 Dec:000201    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH ACUTE (Lu) (E') &Eacute;
   é    U+00E9 Dec:000233    LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE (Ll) (e') &eacute;
```

The plugin proposes also a `:Digraphs` command to search specifically among the digraphs.

```
:Digraphs é
```

returns

```
É E' 201 é e' 233
```